# Настройка bridge Mikrotik

Tags: mikrotik

Может ли wan интерфейс вынесен в отдельный бридж. Не натятся клиенты.

Comment: может, но в чем у вас проблема вы не написали

Comment: @dash1121 Возникли недопонимания с микротиком, с его истолкованием wan и lan интерфейсов. У меня порты с 2 по 5 в бридже LAN а порт 1 в бридже WAN, нат настроен как src-nat и out interface WAN экшн mascarade. Настроен маршрут по умолчанию, сеть от провайдера я получаю по dhcp. На бридж LAN настроен dhcp сервер с адресом гейта как ip бридж интерфейса LAN. Микротик wan сеть пингует а клиенты нет.

Comment: разрешена ли пересылка(forward) от клиентов(lan) во внешний мир, dhcp-client точно отработал на нужном интерфейсе, маршрут по умолчанию правильный? и много чего можно писать не видя конфига. Давно не видел дефолтового конфига, но кажется там тоже все в бриджи загоняют теперь.

Comment: @dash1121 я удалил дефолтный конфиг. Маршруты у клиентов верные, так как микротик их пингует, иначе ответа бы не было. В цепочку форвард ничего не добавлял, только input и output.

Comment: у всех правил фаервола есть счетчик - если у правила маскарадинга он растет, то значит что пакеты идут не туда/не так, а если нет растет, то пакеты до правила не доходят.

Comment: Счётчик как раз растёт, значит пакеты идут не туда. На микротике 2 маршрута помеченные как непосредственно подключённые (directory connected) одна из них сеть провайдера, вторая сеть клиентов за микротиком.

Comment: Иногда при пинге с одного из адресов клиентов в терминале микротика выходит could not make socket.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96055/discussion-between-dash1121-and-vasiliy-kuramshin).